# Exception Error for balancing parenthesis solution in Python

Tags: python, string, indexing

I am trying to solve this prompt and I got a soltuion wokring until it gets to the last assertion in the function solve. I keeping getting a String Index out of range for line 12, if string[j] == closedB. When I step through the code in Visual studio using breakpoints I find out i is 4 and j is 5 when the error occurs. I have tried to fix it without messing up my code but after hours I am stuck.

I would greatly appreciate any help you can give me!

Thank you!

```
def solve(string: str) -> str:
    """Given a string of unbalanced parenthesis, return the string with the parenthesis balanced without removing any."""
    return string


def test_solve():
    assert solve('(()') == '()()'
    assert solve('))()(') == '()()()()'
```

Here is my code:

````
    """Given a string of unbalanced parenthesis, return the string with the parenthesis balanced without removing any."""
    newString = ""
    stack = []
    openB = "("
    closedB = ")"
    

    for i in range(len(string)):
        j = i + 1
        if string[i] == openB:
            if string[j] == closedB:
                newString += string[i]
                newString += closedB
                continue
            else:
                newString += string[i]
                newString += closedB          
            
        elif string[i] == closedB and string[i] != len(string) - 1 and j <= len(string):
            stack.append(string[i])
            newString += openB
            newString = newString + stack.pop()   
            
    return newString

print(solve('(()'))
print(solve('))()(')) ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the final iteration of the loop, `i` will be the last valid index for `string`. Then you set `j = i + 1`, making `j` one past the last valid index.

Any use of `j` to index `string` on this loop is invalid, which only happens when the last character of the string is an open parentheses.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Do you have any idea how I can replace the j index with something else to compare the next character in the string with the first character?

Comment: @Qi'ra Add a check to see if you are at the end of the string before you check the next character. If you are, and it's an open paren, add a closed paren.

Comment: @Qi'ra Since my answer solved the original question. could you accept it as the answer? This closes the question.

Comment: Sorry I didn't know I was supposed to do that.